react-native-video showing white Screen for 1 min then playing video
I am using this package to show video which I am getting fro pubnub message block , the require ment is once the video push from pubnub it will save locally
but video is playing first time push but after killing app and opening again it showing blank white screen for long time and then shows the video i tried to managed by states but unable to handle this issue
import React, { useEffect, useState,useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image, ActivityIndicator, } from 'react-native';
import PubNub from 'pubnub';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const [mediaUrl, setMediaUrl] = useState('');
  const [displayID, setDisplayID] = useState('loading');
  const [mediaType, setMediaType] = useState('');
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const pubnub = new PubNub({
    // demokeys
    publishKey: 'pub-c-52eb18de-968d-4d2e-8e24-da7d49aac36d',
    subscribeKey: 'sub-c-863ea605-1972-4d02-be58-f9a4bce768fd',
    // productionKeys
    // publishKey: "pub-c-1edcf878-9b9d-4577-a260-21ec35fa5f09",
    // subscribeKey:"sub-c-59a0b640-b45b-4197-8cec-d20851980a5b",
    userId: displayID,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadDataAndSubscribe = async () => {
      let storedShortUuid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('shortUuid');
      let storedMediaUrl = await AsyncStorage.getItem('mediaUrl');
      let storedMediaType = await AsyncStorage.getItem('mediaType');
      if(storedMediaType && storedMediaUrl){
         setMediaUrl(storedMediaUrl);
        setMediaType(storedMediaType);
      }else{
        let downloadedMedia = await AsyncStorage.getItem("localMediaUrl")
        setMediaUrl(downloadedMedia)
      }
     
      if (!storedShortUuid) {
        storedShortUuid = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('shortUuid', storedShortUuid);
      }

      setDisplayID(storedShortUuid);
      subscribeToChannel(storedShortUuid);
     
    };

    loadDataAndSubscribe();
  }, []);

  const downloadMedia = async (mediaUrl, mediaType) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      // Check if the device is online
      const netInfoState = await NetInfo.fetch();
      const isOnline = netInfoState.isConnected;
      
      // If the device is offline, attempt to load the media from local storage
      if (!isOnline) {
        const localMediaUrl = await AsyncStorage.getItem('localMediaUrl');
        if (localMediaUrl) {
          setLoading(false);
          setMediaUrl(localMediaUrl); // Set the media URL in state
          return localMediaUrl;
        }
      }
  
      const response = await RNFetchBlob.config({
        fileCache: true,
      }).fetch('GET', mediaUrl)
        .progress((received, total) => {
          const progress = (received / total) * 100;
          setProgress(progress);
        });
      
      const localPath = response.path();
      
      // Save the media to local storage for offline access
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('localMediaUrl', localPath);
  
      setLoading(false);
      setMediaUrl(localPath); // Set the media URL in state
      return localPath;
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.error('Error downloading media:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const handleMediaPlayback = async (message) => {
    const { mediaUrl, mediaType, downloadLocal } = message;
  
    if (downloadLocal) {
      // Download media locally if required
      const localPath = await downloadMedia(mediaUrl, mediaType);
  
      if (localPath) {
        setMediaUrl(localPath);
        setMediaType(mediaType);
      } else {
        console.error('Media download failed');
      }
    } else {
      // Directly set media URL for playback from remote source
      setMediaUrl(mediaUrl);
      setMediaType(mediaType);
    }
  };

  const subscribeToChannel = (shortUuid) => {
    pubnub.addListener({
      message: async (message) => {
        try {
          if (message && message.message) {
            const messageContent = JSON.parse(message.message);
            handleMediaPlayback(messageContent);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('mediaUrl', messageContent.mediaUrl);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('mediaType', messageContent.mediaType);
          } else {
            console.warn('Received message with missing message property:', message);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing message:', error);
        }
      },
    });

    pubnub.subscribe({ channels: [`screenvu_${shortUuid}`] });
  };
console.log("problem he ",mediaUrl)
console.log("problem2  he ",mediaType)
console.log("ref",videoRef.current)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {loading ? (
      <>
      <Text style={styles.progressText}>{Math.round(progress)}%</Text>
      </>
   
    ) : mediaUrl ? (
      mediaType === 'VIDEO' ? (
        <Video
         ref={videoRef}
          source={{ uri: mediaUrl }}
          style={styles.media}
          controls={false}
          resizeMode="contain"
          repeat={true}
          autoplay={true}
        />
        // <Text style={{color:'red'}}>{mediaUrl}{mediaType}</Text>
      ) : (
        <Image source={{ uri: mediaUrl }} style={styles.media} />
      )
    ) : (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Image source={require('./assets/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />
        <View style={{ height: 30 }}></View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingHorizontal: 35, paddingVertical: 4 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#1846b1', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>{displayID}</Text>
        </View>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </View>
);
  
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  mediaContainer: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
  },
  media: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  logo: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
  },
  loaderContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  progressText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color:"blue",
    alignSelf:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;

I tried to handle by useRef
tried set State is useEffect
